# What happens to small bills if they are unpaid?

Tags: united-states, credit-score, debt-collection, billing

I understand that bills are sold to collection agencies if they are unpaid. But what about very small bills then? For example, say if there is a bill of less than $10.00, will the company bother to sell it at all? What will happen if the small bill remains unpaid?

**Edit**: Does failing to pay such small bills affect one's credit score?

Comment: It might be written off, or it might be sold for computerized auto-collection.  I've seen both happen.

Comment: Thanks @RonJohn! What does computerized auto-collection mean?

Comment: Letters are mailed to you demanding money, instead of someone phoning you and demand the money.  While a human might say, "$10 isn't worth my time", the computer doesn't care: it takes an input file full of debts -- no matter how trivially small -- and addresses  and sends them out.

Comment: @RonJohn, thanks! If after several attempts by the computer the bill still remains unpaid, what will happen then? Will they even bother to sell it to a collection agency?

Comment: Computer programs can be extraordinarily persistent and brain-dead.  As long as it's not paid, it stays in the "unpaid debts" file, and they send it out the next month, escalating to more and more frequent automated phone calls, etc.

Comment: @RonJohn, but it costs them a few cents to send each snail mail, right? If eventually the postage exceeds the bill amount, what's the point of trying to collect this bill?

Comment: @Zuriel a matter of principal. If they stopped people would have no reason to pay in the first place. If you know theyll harass you constantly and forever youll likely just pay immediately.

Comment: @Vality Thank you! Do you happen to know if such unpaid small bill can affect one's credit score at all?

Comment: @Zuriel Legally they can, practically many lenders will not pay the fees and time to report them. So it depends on the lender and how much you annoyed them.

Comment: "*but it costs them a few cents to send each snail mail*" Maybe the computer programmer (or the person who specified the design) wasn't smart enough to think of that.

Comment: what type of bill? Are you a current customer of the business? why do you owe the money?

Comment: One way to recover the cost of the small unpaid bills is to sell it to a collector that able to squeeze some profit by selling the personal data (to many parties). US has a weak data privacy control law, thus there is no way you can prevent this from happening.  To prevent this from happening, you should just pay off the small bills and demand the comapny to delete your record.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep, it is a small internet bill which I am unhappy about.

Comment: We can't really answer exactly how it will impact your credit score, some models ignore very small collections and/or treat different types of accounts differently (i.e. medical collections are less impactful than other types) and/or behave differently if or when you pay the amount off.

Comment: Also - being in the financial industry, I routinely see creditors putting accounts into collections for silly-low amounts, like $7. That's a very small amount of money to potentially screw your credit score up over. It's probably in your best interest to resolve this outstanding bill before it gets put in collections, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Legally many things could happen, the lender could sue you, sell the debt to a collections agency (Possibly aggregated with many other small debts). They could call, mail or otherwise bother you to pay or they could report you to credit agencies.

However all these actions cost the lender expenses which they may or may not be able to recover from you. In the worst case (for you) they could sue you or send the debt to a collection agency who would then bill for you the debt itself and also their expenses for collecting it. These will sometimes be awarded by a court to the collector depending on circumstances.

More likely you will receive mail or robocalls demanding you pay, these could be as little as once a month or even every day if they are determined, but they may not bother if the debt is very small and the costs of doing so exceed it. They also could report you to the credit bureaus to damage your credit report, but this also costs them something.

However if the debt is only a few dollars it is also possible they will just write it off and not bother trying to collect. This doesn't make it legally go away immediately but it will eventually likely roll off due to statute of limitations rules for loans.